# Algorithm of minimizing cost of roads in this graph task

Tags: java, math, graph-theory

Recently I get this task

Based on the system of two-way roads, determine between which cities it is worth building roads so that one can get from any city to any other in less than N km. The distances and construction costs of eligible roads are specified separately. Minimize road construction costs.

I made java graph from two matrix for visualize initial eligible roads, but can't come up with algorithm, I'm not really familiar with graphs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FOR EVER
    M = 0
    LOOP over every pair of cities 
        If min distance ( Dijkstra algorithm ) between cities > M
           M = min distance
    IF M <= N
        BREAK
    LOOP over eligible roads in order of increasing cost
        IF road would reduce distance between two most distant cities
             BUILD the road
```

Note that many implementations of Dijkstra will give the minumim distance from a source to every possible destination.  This can be used to optimize the loop calculating M